# How to scan for wifi devices connected to the same wifi along with their names in Android 10?

Tags: networking, ip, device-discovery

I want to discover my PC's IP from my Android Phone and connect to a local server running at a particular port. Used the Fing tool and it shows the device name and their IP addresses.

[image: image form the fing tool]

How do I implement this in Android 10 and above?
Since arp scanning is no longer allowed by Android 10.
I tried `ip neigh show`
but it returns an empty string.

```
  val runtime = Runtime.getRuntime()
        val proc = runtime.exec("ip neigh show")
        proc.waitFor()
        val reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(proc.inputStream))
        val array = reader.lines().toArray()
```

Is this a good approach or should i host the server on my phone and scan my phone from PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android API 30 or higher curtails the "ip" command, unfortunately, also in the name of protecting MAC addresses